# Devise token auth - Can't create user account after installing devise token authgem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I installed devise token auth gem.https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth#model-concerns

I managed to get routes and all. But unfortuntely the signup is stopped working.

when I try to signup, it shows an error like this.

```
    NoMethodError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
    undefined method `provider' for #<User:0x007f49fd5da2e8>

 Extracted source (around line #433):

  else
    match = match_attribute_method?(method.to_s)
    match ? attribute_missing(match, *args, &block) : super
  end
end
```

Here is my routes

```
   devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
   ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
   devise_for :users
   namespace :api do
     scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
     end
   end
```

According to the documentation, signup requires email, password, and password_confirmation. I'm not what I miss here.

and here is the schema for 'User'

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
t.string   "reset_password_token"
t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
t.datetime "remember_created_at"
t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.string   "authentication_token"
t.string   "provider",                            null: false
t.string   "uid",                    default: "", null: false
t.string   "confirmation_token"
t.datetime "confirmed_at"
t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
t.string   "unconfirmed_email"
t.string   "name"
t.string   "nickname"
t.string   "image"
t.string   "tokens"
end

   add_index "users", ["authentication_token"], name: "index_users_on_authentication_token", using: :btree
   add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
   add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
   add_index "users", ["uid", "provider"], name: "index_users_on_uid_and_provider", unique: true, using: :btree
```

Here is user model

```
     class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules.
      devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
        :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
        :confirmable, :omniauthable
     include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
    has_many :movies
    has_many :reviews

   end
```

This is the POST request which I used for creating user account?

```
    {
    "user": {
    "email": "email@g.com",
    "password": "password12345678",
    "password_confirmation": "password12345678" }

     }
```

and the response was something like this.

```
      {"status":"error","errors":["Please submit proper sign up data in request body."]}
```

Here is the log for corresponding request.

```
  Started POST "/api/v1/auth/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-05-28 15:51:28 +0530
Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::RegistrationsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"user"=>{"email"=>"email@g.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "registration"=>{"user"=>{"email"=>"email@g.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}}}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Unpermitted parameters: user, registration
Filter chain halted as :validate_sign_up_params rendered or redirected
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 4ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

What will be the issue behind that error, how can I solve it?

Comment: Did you run `rake:db:migrate`? Also try restarting your server - if have not done so after adding the gem to your Gemfile.

Comment: @maxcal of course, I verified the same through schema

Comment: @maxcal any idea about debugging it?

Comment: from log, `Unpermitted parameters: user, registration`

seems like I haven't added them into permitted params

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Somehow I managed figured out what missing with the implementation. When I use email authentication, the devise token auth gem requires `uid` and a `provider`.

When we trying to post the request without those parameters, It will fail due to parameter validation. To bypass it, we can generate a `uid` and a `provider` using `before_validation` in the user method.

Here I use `email` as `provider` if the `provider` is blank, and for the `uid`, I use `email` if it is blank.

This is what I wrote in the user model.

```
  before_validation :set_provider
  before_validation :set_uid

  def set_provider
    self[:provider] = "email" if self[:provider].blank?
  end

  def set_uid
    self[:uid] = self[:email] if self[:uid].blank? && self[:email].present?
  end
```

By this way, you will get the necessary parameters for user signup.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by taking the user params out of the :user subhash. I was writing a controller test

`post :create, { email: "user@example.org", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password" }`

worked and

`post :create, {user: { email: "user@example.org", password: "password", password_confirmation: "password" }}`

Answer (score 0):

You can also set `uid` with a token generated by Devise.

```
Devise.friendly_token.first(10)
```