# How to implement signup/login for a mobile application with rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have application which is written with ruby on rails. I want to implement signup/login from the mobile application. I usually use devise in web application. But I have no idea about how to implement login/signup features using JSON requests and responses.

I tried to use devise token auth and I'm stuck in the middle. [Devise token auth - Can't create user account after installing devise token authgem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496770/devise-token-auth-cant-create-user-account-after-installing-devise-token-auth)

Is there anyway to implement authentication it in a similar way?

The flow will be like >

User enter mail address and password > send a POST request to server >

User send some request to protected controllers and server respond to it if he is signed in

Comment: Vote to close: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

If you want help, please show your specific issue, with the code that is not working and any error messages

Comment: @dax I did the same in the question which is linked above. In that question, I showed code, error messages and everything. But I haven't find a solution. That's why I asked for broad question. After all, I want to solve the problem, It will be great if I can find a better solution.

Comment: so you're asking a question about another question that you've already asked?

Comment: @dax that question is about fixing specific issue with devise token auth gem, But I couldn't find a solution for that. This one about signup/login implementation with rails. It will be great if somebody can help me to find a better way than devise token auth gem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will have to make your back-end(ie devise json ready) you can use proper implementations for you from :

1. [link 1](http://blog.andrewray.me/how-to-set-up-devise-ajax-authentication-with-rails-4-0/)
2. [link 2](http://natashatherobot.com/devise-sign-up-ajax-rails/)

or of-course you can search for proper solution.

Next is, you need to keep a track of csrf token provided by application to avoid the invalid CSRF token warnings

Comment: thank you maan! Finally I did it :)

Comment: But It doesn't use tokens, right? How should I get it work with mobile app?

Comment: Devise changes CSRF token when you sign in/sign out.
just keep the csrf token in each json response and use this token for next request